# New to Apex working on resolving a duplicate record when a user edits the sibling

Tags: apex, trigger

Long store short I have two case comment objects.
For ease of understanding we will call these 
StandardComment and Support comment

Based on criteria either the support commented will be replicated in the case Commo object or vice versa and there is some steps in place to prevent duplicate, but that is the main issue I am working on right now.

I am currently trying to populate the newly created CaseCommentId in a customer Support comment.

I did have that working but when I additional requirements for difference scenarios it go broke.

Can any one lead me in the right direction.  I feel like I am so close.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger createCaseComment on Support_Comment__c (after insert, after update) {

    Id Id;
    Id ccId;
    string commentBody = null;

    List<Support_Comment__c> supportComments = new List<Support_Comment__c>();

        for (Support_Comment__c newSupportComment : Trigger.new) {
            Id = newSupportComment.Id;
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                    System.debug('The newSupportComment Id = ' + Id);
                if (newSupportComment.Comment__c != null && newSupportComment.Community_User__c == 'Standard User' && newSupportComment.Public__c == true){
                    if (stoprecurssion.runonce()){

                        commentBody = newSupportComment.Comment__c;

                        CaseComment cComment = new CaseComment(ParentId = newSupportComment.Case__c, CommentBody = newSupportComment.Comment__c, IsPublished = TRUE);
                        database.insert(cComment);
                        ccId = cComment.Id;
                        System.debug('The new standard Comment Id = ' + ccId);

                        Support_Comment__c supComsToUpdate = new Support_Comment__c(Id = newSupportComment.Id, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c = ccId);
                        supportComments.add(supComsToUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }
            update supportComments;
        }

        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            Support_Comment__c oldSupportComment = Trigger.oldMap.get(Id);
            String oldComBody = oldSupportComment.Comment__c;
            Boolean isPub = oldSupportComment.Public__c;

            Support_Comment__c updatedComment = [SELECT Id, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c FROM Support_Comment__c WHERE Id =:oldSupportComment.Id];
            //updatedComment.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c = ccId;
            CaseComment cCommentUpdate = [SELECT Id, ParentId, CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId =:oldSupportComment.Case__c];

            if (updatedComment.Public__c == TRUE && oldSupportComment.Comment__c == oldComBody && cCommentUpdate.Id == oldSupportComment.Id) {

                cCommentUpdate.CommentBody = updatedComment.Comment__c;
                database.update(cCommentUpdate);
            }
            if (updatedComment.Public__c == FALSE && oldSupportComment.Comment__c == oldComBody && cCommentUpdate.Id == oldSupportComment.Id) {

                delete(cCommentUpdate);
            }
            List<Support_Comment__c> privateSupportComments = new List<Support_Comment__c>();

            for (Support_Comment__c updatedSupComPrivate : Trigger.new) {
                Id = updatedSupComPrivate.Id;

                if (oldSupportComment.Public__c == FALSE && updatedSupComPrivate.Public__c == TRUE && updatedSupComPrivate.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c == null) {
                    if (stoprecurssion.runonce()) {

                        CaseComment cCommentAdd = new CaseComment(ParentId = updatedSupComPrivate.Case__c);
                        cCommentAdd.CommentBody = updatedSupComPrivate.Comment__c;
                        cCommentAdd.IsPublished = TRUE;

                        database.insert(cCommentAdd);
                        ccId = cCommentAdd.Id;

                        Support_Comment__c privateSupComsToUpdate = new Support_Comment__c(Id = updatedSupComPrivate.Id, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c = ccId);
                        privateSupportComments.add(privateSupComsToUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }
            update privateSupportComments;
        }
    }
```

If you have any insight please advise.

Thanks

Comment: N.B. `recurssion` is spelled `recursion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your trigger isn't bulk safe. You have queries nested inside of for loops that could cause you to exceed the limit of 100 queries per execution context. You also have your update to SupportComments located inside of a for loop which could cause you to exceed the limit on 150 DML operations per execution context. It also means that you keep updating the previously updated records in that list every time you add a new record to it.

I also believe you need to relocate your call to `stoprecurssion.runonce()` since it too is located inside of a for loop. If it does what I suspect it does (tests a public static boolean and returns it's value; setting to false *after* first time it's called), it would only allow your AfterInsert logic to run for one record that meets your criteria. Further, if there's any workflow that executes after this trigger executes, then the AfterUpdate portion of it will be called following the workflow.

Because of that, you really only want this entire trigger to run once and only once. The above call should be located at the start of your trigger before you enter any of your for loops.

Here's a general outline of what I think you need to do to fix your trigger:

```
trigger createCaseComment on Support_Comment__c (after insert, after update) {

   // declare your variables as you currently do

   if (stoprecurssion.runonce()){

      if(trigger.isAfter){

         for (Support_Comment__c newSupportComment : Trigger.new) {
            Id = newSupportComment.Id;
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
               if (newSupportComment.Comment__c != null && newSupportComment.Community_User__c == 'Standard User' && newSupportComment.Public__c == true){

                  // .... run your logic

               }
            }
         } // end for loop
         update supportComments;        

         if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            // you need a for loop here on trigger.new 
            // there is no record context without it
            list<Support_Comment__c>oldSupportComments = new list<Support_Comment__c>();
            Set<Id>SuppCommentIds = new set<Id>();
            SuppCommentIds = Trigger.newmap.keyset();
            map<Id,Id>commentId2CaseMap = new map<Id,Id>();
            map<Id,string>commentId2CaseBodyMap = new map<Id,string>();
            map<Id,boolean>commentId2isPubMap = new map<Id,boolean>();
            for(Support_Comment__c sc : trigger.new){

               new Support_Comment__c oldSupportComment = Trigger.oldMap.get(sc.Id);
               String oldComBody = oldSupportComment.Comment__c;
               commentId2CaseBodyMap.put(oldSupportComment.Id,oldComBody);
               Boolean isPub = oldSupportComment.Public__c;
               commentId2isPubMap.put(oldSupportComment.Id,isPub);
               commentId2CaseMap.put(oldSupportComment.Id,oldSupportComment.Case__c);
               oldSupportComments.add(oldSupportComment);

            // you now have maps and lists of everything you need to run bulk queries and process the results

            } // end for loop

            list<Support_Comment__c> updatedComments = [SELECT Id, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c FROM Support_Comment__c WHERE Id IN: SuppCommentIds];

            list<CaseComment> cCommentUpdate = [SELECT Id, ParentId, CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId IN: commentId2CaseMap.values()];

            // I strongly suspect these could be combined into a single query, 
            // perhaps using a subquery, but don't know the relationships to do that for you

         // continue trigger logic using a new for loop...
```

I'll leave it to you to finish the rest of the trigger using the relationships I've created for you and the above patterns. You should be almost there.